# Getting specific date with timezone in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, datetime-format

I am getting a little crazy with date and time libraries in Java. Basically what I need is to get two String dates, the first one corresponds to the previous day in Australia time (taking into account daylight time) with a specific hour (will come as a parameter) and with the following date format: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz"`.

Consider I will receive the time as a string like the following: `"180000"`. So if today is Nov-17 in Australia, I will need to get the following String:

```
"2017-11-16T18:00:00.000 AEDT"
```

And the second string date I need is the same day as today in au time:

```
"2017-11-17T18:00:00.000 AEDT"
```

I am not able to use JDK 8, I must use JDK 7.

I tried different ways but I am not getting what I need. Any suggestion will be great.

Comment: How can previous day be 2 days before today? Or rather, if today is Nov-17, how can "same day as today" be 2017-11-18? --- BTW: The main class you're looking for to use for this is [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Comment: @Andreas thanks, just a typo

Comment: btw I am not able to use jdk8, I must use jdk7

Comment: In that case, @fabrik, I warmly recommend you use [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) with your JDK 7. This is the backport of the modern JSR-310 date and time API to Java 6 and 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your comment that you cannot use Java 8, you must use JDK 7. At the same time, especially for not quite trivial run-of-the-mill operations like yours, `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API that came out with Java 8 in 2014 is so much nicer to work with. Fortunately the modern API has been backported to Java 6 and 7 too, in the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (that’s ThreeTen for [JSR-310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where the API was first described). So I encourage you to get the backport and start coding:

```
    ZoneId australianTime = ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney");
    DateTimeFormatter receivedTimeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss");
    DateTimeFormatter neededDateTimeFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz", 
                                          Locale.forLanguageTag("en-AU"));
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(australianTime);
    LocalDate yesterday = today.minusDays(1);
    String receivedTimeString = "180000";
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(receivedTimeString, receivedTimeFormat);
    String previousDayAtTime = yesterday.atTime(time)
            .atZone(australianTime)
            .format(neededDateTimeFormatter);
    System.out.println(previousDayAtTime);
```

When I ran this snippet today, it printed the requested output for yesterday:

```
2017-11-16T18:00:00.000 AEDT
```

I trust you to do similarly for today.

Since you had AEDT in your requested result, I picked Australia/Sydney as time zone over Australia/Darwin or other Australian options.

Using the backport is also the futureproof solution: you will need the backport only until one day you upgrade to Java 8 or later (Java 9 is out already). When upgrading, simply change your `import` statement from  `org.threeten.bp` to `java.time`.